# Bootstrap Popover on Input : hover

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, popover

I'm using simple form and trying to get the popover working for an Input.

The NEW form Input:

```
<p>
          <%= f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'login-form-block',
                                            id: "login-form-selector",
                                            data: { :toggle => 'popover',
                                                    :trigger => 'hover',
                                                    :content => 'Some popover content' }},
                      :autofocus=>true, label: false, placeholder: "Title",
                      :hint => "Enter a Title for your Clip" %>
        </p>
```

I added `addclips.js` to vendors/assets/javascripts and `//= require addclips.js` in my application.js

My addclips.js file looks like this:

```
$('#login-form-selector').popover()
```

Could someone help me combine everything together and explain me the Javascript i have to include to get this working, for my input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to show in the popover, but getting it to trigger on hover for your input field will require some bootstrap `data-` attributes in the tag for the popover options, and one javascript method call.

The tag output should have `data-` attributes similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/me8Cb/

**Rails**

```
<p>
    <%= f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'login-form-block', id: 'login-form-selector', data-toggle: 'popover', data-trigger: 'hover', data-content: 'Some popover content' },
                :autofocus=>true, label: false, placeholder: "Title",
                :hint => "Enter a Title for your Clip" %>
</p>
```

**JS w/ jQuery and Bootstrap**

```
$('#login-form-selector').popover();
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this working, i updated my question with the code i have now. my js is -> $('login-form-selector').popover(). I think i am not calling right my js file.

Comment: You need to call the method on the input element. Try `$('#login-form-selector input').popover();`

Comment: I added a few id's in the code, i had already your code in my js file. but somehow it didn't want to work :((

Comment: It looks like you have conflicting ids now between your `<p>` and input. You can either remove one of them or name your input id something different so you can do `$('#your-input-id').popover();` for your method call.

Comment: I figured the right way to include id out. But still no popups 3:(, i strongly believe my js isn't called .

Comment: I'd inspect your page when it loads, see if you have any JS errors, check to see if `addclips.js` is being included. You can also call the bootstrap method right in a `<script>` tag to help debug. I'm assuming you're using bootstrap successfully already and all its assets are loading.

Comment: yeah Did that, it's loading the js file. Could you give a quick look at my repo -> https://github.com/Theminijohn/myapp .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36611/discussion-between-chucknelson-and-the-mini-john)